# How to fix this UnicodeDecodeError that says "invalid continuation byte"?

Tags: python

I'm following along with a sentiment analysis tutorial (https://pythonprogramming.net/sentiment-analysis-python-textblob-vader/). How would I go about fixing this error?

I tried changing how to go line by line but I don't think that is the problem. Somehow I have to convert the way the text is encoded?

```
pos_count = 0
pos_correct = 0

with open("positive.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        analysis = TextBlob(line)
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
            pos_correct += 1
        pos_count +=1


neg_count = 0
neg_correct = 0

with open("negative.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        analysis = TextBlob(line)
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0:
            neg_correct += 1
        neg_count +=1

print("Positive accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(pos_correct/pos_count*100.0, pos_count))
print("Negative accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(neg_correct/neg_count*100.0, neg_count))
```

```
  File "/Users/adixit/PycharmProjects/sentiment_analysis/Tutorial.py", line 15, in <module>
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 4645: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make a [mre]

Comment: I downloaded `positive.txt`. `file` says it contains "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with LF, NEL line terminators". So you'll need to figure out its encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open

> In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: locale.getpreferredencoding(False) is called to get the current locale encoding

On your system the default encoding is `utf-8`, while Firefox detects the encoding of https://pythonprogramming.net/static/downloads/short_reviews/positive.txt as "Western".

You need to specify the correct encoding, like:

```
with open("positive.txt", "r", encoding="windows-1252") as f:
```